# C++ template function for object construction

Tags: c++, macros

I'm looking for a solution to my current problem: I use new placement and for this I do "macro-magic" to execute 3 steps in one:

```
// macro magic
#define sys_construct(ptr,mem,type)   \
    assert(!ptr);                     \
    ptr = new(mem) type;              \
    assert(ptr)

// my member
osif::I_List uartFifo;
uint8_t mem_uartFifo[sizeof(Fifo)];

// object construction
sys_construct(uartFifo, mem_uartFifo, Fifo("myFifo"));
```

This works fine but is macros-based which I'm no big fan of.

I'm looking for a solution (haven't found one yet) that would look like the following:

```
template<typename T_PTR, typename T_MEM, typename T_TYPE>
inline static void sys_construct(T_PTR ptr, T_MEM mem, T_TYPE type)
{
  assert(!ptr);
  ptr = new(mem) type;
  assert(ptr);
}
```

The issue is mainly with my type: how can I input "Fifo("myFifo")" into a function?

Comment: I can't see how `Fifo("myFifo")` can be a type.

Comment: Yes i thought so. But maybe someone knows some tricks.

Comment: `new` can't return `nullptr` unless you specify [`std::nothrow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow). It will instead throw [`std::bad_alloc`[(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) on faiilure. Your second assert is redundant.

Comment: ah forgot this, i cannot use exceptions... compiler is not allowed thorugh -noexeption..

Comment: @ambedded Then your assert is still redundant. As far as I know, most implementation will just terminate if you would throw in a non-throwing build. In any case, a conforming compiler should not have `new` return `nullptr` in any case where `std::nothrow` isn't used. That includes using platform specific such as disabling exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

With template you might have following with little different call syntax:

```
template <typename T, typename Ptr, typename ...Ts >
void sys_construct(T& ptr, uint8_t* mem, Ts&&... args)
{
    ptr = new (mem) T(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

With usage

```
sys_construct<Fifo>(*uartFifo, mem_uartFifo, "myFifo");
```

Comment: ha! ok. that looks cool and is close to my current usage. thank you ill give it a go

Comment: I think there is a *type-o*. Its a pun, because i think you mean `T`, not `type`.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox: More than one typo in fact ;-) Fixed.